# Simple Birth Death Process

Tags: random, simulation, ecology, iteration

I am trying to implement simple birth death process. Why my code does not work? Any suggestion. Thanks. Cross posted http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1205656

```
birthDeath[λ_, μ_, initialPopulation_, numOfReaction_] :=     
 NestList[(
    Δt1 =  RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[λ  #]];
    Δt2 = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[μ #]]; 
    If[Δt1 < Δt2, {# + 1}, {# - 1}]) &,  initialPopulation, numOfReaction]

birthDeath[3, 1, 10, 2]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *How can I store Δt = Min[Δt1, Δt2] so that I can plot time vs population*

One way is

```
birthDeath2[λ_, μ_, initialPopulation_, numOfReaction_] :=
        NestList[(Δt1 = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[λ #[[2]]]];
                Δt2 =   RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[μ #[[2]]]];
                {Min[Δt1, Δt2],  If[Δt1 < Δt2, #[[2]] + 1, #[[2]] - 1]}) &,
  {0, initialPopulation}, numOfReaction]

{Δt, pop} = Transpose[birthDeath2[3, 1, 10, 10]];
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Accumulate@Δt, pop}], InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks kglr. That's helped a lot.

Comment: @okkes, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 6):

Here is improved version

```
   exact[\[Lambda]_, \[Mu]_, initialPopulation_] := 
 Module[{}, 
  DSolveValue[{p'[t] == (\[Lambda] - \[Mu]) p[t], 
    p[0] == initialPopulation}, p[t], t]]; 
birthDeath[\[Lambda]_, \[Mu]_, initialPopulation_, numOfReaction_] := 
 NestList[(\[CapitalDelta]t1 = 
     RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[\[Lambda] #[[2]]]];
    \[CapitalDelta]t2 = 
     RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[\[Mu] #[[2]]]];
    \[CapitalDelta]t = Min[\[CapitalDelta]t1, \[CapitalDelta]t2];
    {#[[1]] + \[CapitalDelta]t, 
     If[\[CapitalDelta]t1 < \[CapitalDelta]t2, #[[2]] + 1, #[[2]] - 
       1]}) &, {0, initialPopulation}, numOfReaction]


With[{\[Lambda] = 3, \[Mu] = 1, initialPopulation = 10, 
  numOfReaction = 1000, numOfsim = 10},
 sim = Table[
   birthDeath[\[Lambda], \[Mu], initialPopulation, numOfReaction], 
   numOfsim];
 Show[ListStepPlot[sim, PlotLegends -> {"Simulation"}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[0.2]], Frame -> True, 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed", FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Population"}, 
   ImageSize -> Large], 
  Plot[Evaluate@exact[\[Lambda], \[Mu], initialPopulation], {t, 0, 
    Max@sim[[All, -1, 1]]}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"ODE"}], 
  ListLinePlot[Mean@sim, PlotLegends -> {"Avg of Simulation"}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I just did this in class today using @IstvánZachar's `GillespieSSA` function from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119788/6358).  Load that, then:

```
ClearAll[n];
reactions = {n -> 2 n, n -> Null};
b0 = 3;
d0 = 2;
rates = {b0, d0};
init = <|n -> 10|>;

tmax = 1;

sto = GillespieSSA[reactions, init, rates, {0, tmax}];
ListLinePlot[sto, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotRange -> {0, All}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For fun, here's a version with density-dependent mortality:

```
ClearAll[n];
reactions = {n -> 2 n, n -> Null, 2 n -> Null};
b0 = 3;
d0 = 1;
d1 = 0.01;
rates = {b0, d0, d1};
init = <|n -> 10|>;

tmax = 10;

sto = GillespieSSA[reactions, init, rates, {0, tmax}];
ListLinePlot[sto, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotRange -> {0, All}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks Chris. I saw that fabulous implementation, but it is too advanced for me. I can't follow some part of the code. So I decided to make my own code to understand to process.

Comment: Nice application Chris! Thanks for the mention!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. If should be `If[Δt1 < Δt2, # + 1, # - 1]`

```
birthDeath[λ_, μ_, initialPopulation_, numOfReaction_] :=     
 NestList[(
    Δt1 =  RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[λ  #]];
    Δt2 = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[μ #]]; 
    If[Δt1 < Δt2, # + 1, # - 1]) &,  initialPopulation, numOfReaction]

birthDeath[3, 1, 10, 2]
```

Comment: How can I store $ \Delta t=Min[ \Delta t_1, \Delta t_2] $ so that I can plot time vs population

Answer (score 1):

Just to "automate":

```
f[b_, d_, n0_, n_] := 
 NestList[Function[u, 
   If[u[[2]] == 0, u, 
    u + {Min[#1, #2], Sign[#2 - #1]} & @@ {RandomVariate[
       ExponentialDistribution[b u[[2]]]], 
      RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[d u[[2]]]]}]], {0, n0}, n]
vis[b_, d_, n0_, n_, m_] := 
 Module[{tab = Table[f[b, d, n0, n], m], mx},
  mx = Max[(Join @@ tab)[[All, 1]]];
  Show[ListStepPlot[tab, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[0.2]], Frame -> True, 
    PlotTheme -> "Detailed", FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Population"}, 
    ImageSize -> Large], ListStepPlot[Mean@tab, PlotStyle -> Red], 
   Plot[n0 Exp[(b - d) t], {t, 0, mx}, PlotStyle -> Dashed]]]
```

So,

```
Manipulate[
 vis[birth, death, initial, n, 
  m], {birth, {1.1, 3, 5}}, {death, {1, 2.5, 3.5}}, {initial, {10, 
   20}}, {n, {100, 1000}}, {m, {5, 10, 20}}]
```

[image]