# Any built-in function for this code?

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics, random

Is there any build in function or shorter version of this? Assume I have 3 reactions time and each reaction occurs randomly. Generate `rand=RandomReal[]` if rand<0.2 then result is 1, if rand<0.5 then result is 2 and if rand<1 then result is 3. Thanks..

```
 reaction = {0.2, 0.5, 1};
 First@Flatten@Position[reaction, SelectFirst[reaction, RandomReal[] < # &]]
```

Comment: Do you mean `With[{q = RandomReal[]}, First@Flatten@Position[reaction, SelectFirst[reaction, q < # &]]]`
`

Comment: Not really. Maybe `MapIndex` or `Ordering`

Comment: `wd=WeightedData[Range[3],Differences[{0, ##&@@reaction}]];
First@RandomSample[wd,1]`?

Comment: shorter: `First@FirstPosition[reaction,_?(#>RandomReal[]&)]`?

Comment: @kglr I can accept your solution if there is no shorter one. Please write as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wd = WeightedData[Range[3], Differences[{0, ## & @@ reaction}]]; 

SeedRandom[1]
RandomChoice[wd]
```

> 3

```
RandomChoice[wd, 5]
```

> {1,3,1,2,1}

**Update:** a shorter alternative using `FirstPosition`

```
SeedRandom[123]
FirstPosition[reaction - RandomReal[], _?Positive][[1]]
```

> 2

Note: This function uses a single random number while the alternative

```
FirstPosition[reaction, _?(#>RandomReal[]&)][[1]]
```

creates a new random number for every comparison until the condition is satisfied (as does the code in OP), and hence, it can give a different result

```
SeedRandom[123]
FirstPosition[reaction, _?(#>RandomReal[]&)][[1]]
```

> 3

Comment: I'll go with this since it is more readable for me. `First@FirstPosition[reaction,_?(RandomReal[]<#&)]`

Comment: `First@FirstPosition[reaction,_?(RandomReal[]<#&)]` does not work in Do loop  but this works perfectly `FirstPosition[reaction - RandomReal[], _?Positive][[1]]`  see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165073/birth-death-process-with-delay/172031#172031

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you meant to only use one [`RandomReal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomReal) call (per @Coolwater's comment), you can use [`RandomChoice`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomChoice):

```
RandomChoice[{.2, .3 ,.5} -> {1, 2, 3}]
RandomChoice[{.2, .3 ,.5} -> {1, 2, 3}, 10]
```

> 3
>
> {3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1}

**Addendum**

To mimic the OP code with [`RandomChoice`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomChoice), by changing the random number for each comparison, you just need to adjust the probabilities. 20% of the time, the first random number is less than .2. Of the other 80%, 50% of the time the second random number is less than .5, and 50% of the time it is greater than .5. So, the following should produce the same distribution as the OP function:

```
RandomChoice[{.2, .4, .4} -> {1, 2, 3}]
```

We can check by running the OP code multiple times:

```
reaction = {0.2, 0.5, 1};
data = Table[First@Flatten@Position[reaction, SelectFirst[reaction, RandomReal[] < # &]], {10^5}];

Counts[data]/10.^5
```

> <|1 -> 0.20025, 2 -> 0.4018, 3 -> 0.39795|>

Comment: What I want is generate random number `rand=RandomReal[]` and look at its location in reaction and extract index of reaction.

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci I think that's exactly what my function does. 20% of the time, the random number is less than .2, 30% of the time the random number is between .2 and .5 and 50% of the time it is more than .5.

Comment: `RandomChoice[{.2, .3 ,.5} -> {1, 2, 3}]` might be equivalent what I am doing. I will think about it.

Comment: When I replaced your code with mine it does not give desired result.

Comment: This looks  right to me. Clarify why the result is not as desired.

Comment: what if reaction is reaction={0.999998, 0.999999, 1.};

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci - your code (generating a random number for each test done by `SelectFirst`) is equivalent to `RandomChoice[{0.2, 0.4, 0.4} -> Range[3]]` since the first test extracts ~20%, if the second test is needed it extracts ~50% of the remaining ~80% (i.e., ~40%), and the last test will extract all of the remaining. Using a single random number gives the result that Carl provides `RandomChoice[{0.2, 0.3, 0.5} -> Range[3]]`

Comment: One can find complete  code here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158300/michaelis-menten-kinetics-using-gillespie-algorithm/158543#158543

Comment: your question implies `{.2,.5,1}` is fixed. The generalization is `RandomChoice[Differences@Prepend[reaction, 0] -> Range[3], 100]`  (assume the last element is always 1 )

Comment: I liked @CarlWoll solution but for some reason it does not work.

Comment: Yes last element in reaction is always 1 sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to make this a *distribution* and then use all the machinery that goes with that:

```
SeedRandom["December 27, 2017"];
distReaction = With[
    {
       reaction = {0.2, 0.5, 1}
    },
    EmpiricalDistribution[ Differences[{0} ~ Join ~ reaction ] -> Range[3] ]
]


RandomVariate[ distReaction, 5 ]
```

> {2, 1, 3, 3, 3}

We could then ask for the probability of this specific result assuming that the results are i.i.d.:

```
Probability[ 
    {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5} == {2, 1, 3, 3, 3}, 
    Thread [ {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5} \[Distributed] distReaction ]
]
```

> 0.0075

Answer (score 1):

The first response that came to mind, after reading the question, was

```
BlockRandom[
 With[{rand = RandomReal[]},

  Which[
   rand <= 0.2, reaction[[1]],
   0.2 < rand <= 0.5, reaction[[2]],
   0.5 < rand <= 1, reaction[[3]]]], RandomSeeding -> 123456798]
```

where, obviously, `reaction = {0.2, 0.5, 1}`. By replacing `reaction[[i]]` with `i` it is easy to obtain the index of the reaction (not the time it takes).

I think that, this is as literal an implementation as it gets.

A couple of other approaches are

```
BlockRandom[
 With[{rand = RandomReal[]},

  Extract[
   reaction,
   First[Position[Thread[rand <= reaction], True]]]
  ], RandomSeeding -> 123456798]
```

and

```
BlockRandom[
 With[{rand = RandomReal[]},

  Last[Flatten[Reap[
     Scan[
      If[rand <= #, Sow[#]; Return[]] &, reaction]]]]
  ], RandomSeeding -> 123456798]
```

In the former of the last two approaches, the index of the reaction instead of it's time can be obtained by replacing `Extract[<>]` with `First[Flatten[Position[Thread[rand <= reaction], True]]]`.

The later code segment cannot be readily adjusted to obtain the index of the reaction instead of the time (at least not without doing something like `First@Position[reaction, x]` where `x` stands for the output of the last approach)