# Sample the data with equal step size

Tags: sampling

I have the data below. I would like to sample with equal step size. For simplicity lets try unit step size. Here is the desired result. Find the first time exceed the unit time step, and take lower ones second entry.  `{{1,0},{2,0},{3,3},{4,10},{5,17},{6,27},{7,43},{8,63}}` and so on.

This suppose to work but it does not.

```
iFun = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0];
τ = 1;
range = Range[0, data[[-1, 1]], τ];
data2 = Transpose@{range, iFun@range};



SeedRandom@2 
    A = 30;
    \[Beta] = 0.05;
    {a, b} = {72, 1/12};

X = x = 0;

currentTime = 0;
stackTime = {};
data = Prepend[Join @@ Last@Reap@Do[

       a1 = A   ;
       a2 = \[Beta] X;
       a0 = Total@{a1, a2};
       reactionVec = 1/a0 Accumulate@{a1, a2};

       reaction = 
        First@FirstPosition[reactionVec - RandomReal[], _?Positive];

       tDelay = RandomVariate@GammaDistribution[a, b];

       tWait = RandomVariate@ExponentialDistribution[a0];

       currentTime = currentTime + tWait;

       stackTime = Sort@stackTime;

       minStack = Min[stackTime];

       Which[

        currentTime < minStack,


        Which[

         reaction == 1, {Sow@{currentTime, X}, 
          AppendTo[stackTime, currentTime + tDelay]},

         reaction == 2, {Sow@{currentTime, X -= 1}}],


        minStack < currentTime, 

        {Sow@{minStack, X += 1}, currentTime = minStack, 
         stackTime = Rest@stackTime} ]

       , 1000], {0, x}];
```

Comment: Try this? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169691/801

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also

```
TimeSeriesResample[data, {Range[1, data[[-1, 1]], τ]}]
```

> {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 3}, {4, 10}, {5, 17}, {6, 27}, {7, 43}, {8, 63}}

Comment: This method seems slow for large data. Do you know how to speed it up. I found this but don't know how to modify it. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/169688/how-do-i-transform-my-results-list-manipulation-interpolation/169691#169691

Comment: @Okkes, unfortunately, I don't know how to make tit faster. The linked answer is using `TimeSeriesResample` with additional processing steps. You can use `TimeSeriesResample[TimeSeries[data] , {Range[1, data[[-1, 1]], \[Tau]]}, ResamplingMethod->{"Interpolation",InterpolationOrder->0}]["Path"]` but I doubt this would be faster.

Comment: I meant Carl's solution in the link.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your range specification should start at $1$ if that is what you want the first abscissa to be; you were starting at $0$ instead.
2. Use `Floor` to get the floor of your interpolated function value.

In other words, try this:

```
iFun = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
τ = 1;
range = Range[1, data[[-1, 1]], τ];
data2 = Transpose@{range, Floor@iFun@range}

(* Out: {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 3}, {4, 10}, {5, 17}, {6, 27}, {7, 43}, {8, 63}} *)
```

Comment: I used to use this approach, but when there is a death `Floor` is underestimate the population.. See here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165073/birth-death-process-with-delay

Comment: Desired result is {11, 142}, but your solution gives {11, 141}.

Answer (score 1):

Here is faster way to do it. I modified the code that I found  [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/169688/how-do-i-transform-my-results-list-manipulation-interpolation/169691#169691)

```
SeedRandom@2
A = 30;
\[Beta] = 0.05;
{a, b} = {72, 1/12};

X = x = 0;

currentTime = 0;
stackTime = {};
data = Prepend[Join @@ Last@Reap@Do[a1 = A;
       a2 = \[Beta] X;
       a0 = Total@{a1, a2};
       reactionVec = 1/a0 Accumulate@{a1, a2};

       tWait = RandomVariate@ExponentialDistribution[a0];

       currentTime = currentTime + tWait;

       stackTime = Sort@stackTime;

       minStack = Min[stackTime];

       Which[

        currentTime < minStack,


        reaction = 
         First@FirstPosition[reactionVec - RandomReal[], _?Positive];
        Which[reaction == 1,


         {Sow@{currentTime, X}, 
          AppendTo[stackTime, 
           currentTime + RandomVariate@GammaDistribution[a, b]]},

         reaction == 2, {Sow@{currentTime, X -= 1}}],

        minStack < currentTime, {Sow@{minStack, X += 1}, 
         currentTime = minStack, stackTime = Rest@stackTime}], 
       500000], {0, x}];
```

TimeSeriesResample Method:

```
\[Tau] = 1;
data2 = TimeSeriesResample[
    data, {Range[0, data[[-1, 1]], \[Tau]]}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {10.5438, Null}

```
StepFunction[data_] := 
 Module[{sdata, nf}, sdata = Sort@data; 
  nf = Nearest[sdata[[All, 1]] -> "Index"];
  StepFunction[nf, sdata[[All, 1]], sdata[[All, 2]], {-1, 0}]]

StepFunction[nf_NearestFunction, x_, y_, clip_][pt_List] := 
 With[{near = nf[pt][[All, 1]]}, 
  Join[List@
    pt, {y[[Clip[
      near + Clip[Sign[Subtract[pt, x[[near]]]], clip], {1, 
       Length[x]}]]]}]]
data3 = Transpose@
    StepFunction[data][
     Range[0, data[[-1, 1]], \[Tau]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.439258, Null}

```
data2 == data3
```

> True