# ContinuousMarkovProcess built-in function

Tags: built-in-symbols

Is the built-in function ContinuousMarkovProcess in Mathematica is the well-known Gillespie algorithm?

Comment: `ContinuousMarkovProcess` is not an algorithm; it's a symbolic representation of a mathematical object.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit How does this related to the Gillespie algorithm?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the Gellespie algorithm or the exact mathematical problem it tries to solve. A quick glance at wikipedia suggests the two are related, but I can't really say much more than that.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Any question that inquires about the internal workings of the software or a particular algorithm in use etc. requires developer level knowledge from either WRI or a professional consultant. Can you please make the question more concrete by including any Mathematica code that you have tried out so far. Thanks.

Comment: @Syed Thanks. I will make the question more concrete.

Comment: `RandomFunction[ContinuousMarkovProcess[]]` seems to use the Gillespie algorithm, but I can't find that in the documentation.  You might write Wolfram support and ask. I find its syntax is kind of inconvenient and prefer @IstvánZachar's [implementation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119788/).  I think Robert Nachbar's [Compartmental Modeling pacakge](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/RobertNachbar/CompartmentalModeling/) also implements it.