# How to reproduce the Lotka-Volterra predator-prey dynamics results?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

In Section 2 of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119786/gillespie-stochastic-simulation-algorithm), the stochastic Lotka-Volterra predator-prey dynamics is demonstrated. I have difficulties to reproduce these results. At the end of the mentioned answer, a code is provided, but when I run it, it gives me errors. Any help is appreciated to reproduce these plots by this particular approach.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the errors you get?

Comment: @ChrisK For example, in the syntax of the code there are extra brackets and so forth.

Comment: @ChrisK I'm also trying to compare the results of this approach with when one uses ItoProcess built-in function and uses stochastic differential equations. I have not obtained also meaningful results for my second approach. But, I think, I should post this for another question.

Comment: I just copied the code from the [linked answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119786/gillespie-stochastic-simulation-algorithm) and it worked as expected.

Comment: @ChrisK I don't know what I'm missing here. Could you post it as an aswer?

Comment: Start a fresh Mathematica kernel, copy/paste/run the `GillespieSSA` code, then copy/paste/run the `Lotka-Volterra predator-prey dynamics` code.

Comment: @ChrisK I'm working on Wolfram Cloud Basic. Could be due to this? But I will open it in a new browser.

Comment: I just tried it on the Cloud.  When pasting the `GillespieSSA` code, it mistakenly breaks it into different cells.  This is likely the cause of your brackets problem.  As a work-around, I started a new cell by typing `1`, then pasted over it from within the cell.  Then it works.

Comment: @ChrisK Thanks a lot! It works. Just a final question: I'm trying to reproduce this plot by ItoProcess buil-in function and stochastic differential equation. In principle, should I obtain the same result?

Comment: @ChrisK Another stupid question: the Lotka-Volterra predator-prey reactions in the linked answered result in different differential equations as those quoted in the Wikipedia page of Lotka–Volterra equations?

Comment: No the results will differ, this is simulating a discrete-state continuous-time Markov process, while `ItoProcess` solves a continuous-state stochastic differential equation.  I suppose there are many different parameterizations of the LV model.  BTW, I suggest the text "Stochastic Population Processes: Analysis, Approximations, Simulations" by Eric Renshaw. Good luck!